# Strange ping result?

Tags: security, ping

I'm new here. I just would like how this is done?

Here's the scenario of events:
I was pinging randomly some no-ip adresses(i just imagine an adress and ping it)
Every thing is fine, most of situations result nothing. However, while i pinged `spy.no-ip.biz` it resulted that it's hosted in 127.0.0.1 which is `localhost`:

```
user@host:~$ ping spy.no-ip.biz
PING spy.no-ip.biz (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
^C
--- spy.no-ip.biz ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 18 received, 0% packet loss, time 16998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.061/0.083/0.088/0.007 ms

user@host:~$
```

Can you please tell me how this is happened?

Comment: They told me that it's been set up to always point to 127.0.0.1(localhost), But why this adress(spy.no-ip.biz)?

Comment: Look into /etc/hosts file.  Usually if an ip address is aliased to some hostname it'd go there.  For instance ive aliased googles public dns 8.8.8.8 to gdns, so I can ping gdns instead of 8.8.8.8. Also, who are they ?

Comment: Sorry, i looked into /etc/hosts(i'm using adblocking) but i didn't find spy.no-ip.biz so it isn't aliased there, right ?

Comment: The URL resolves to `0.0.0.0` via DNS, so it's not your computer; it's normal.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/hosts` and `route -n`

Answer (score 0):

The webiste spy.no-ip.biz has nothing to do with your local system/host. spy.no-ip.biz is configured globally to be resolved from localhost. You can check/confirm it by other system or network. The result would be same.